# Why getting NoSuchElementException for nested Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, nosuchelementexception

```
for(Iterator<Suit> i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
          for(Iterator<Rank> j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext();)
            deck.add(new Card(i.next(), j.next()));
```

Someone please explain why am i getting "NoSuchElementException" for these lines of code? I have solution how to avoid, however i want to know why exception thrown. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Think of `i` has `4` elements `{1,2,3,4}` nd `j` has `5` elements `{a,b,c,d,e}`

When you are iterating the inner loop till the elemt of `d` with iterator `j` it will be fine as iterator `i` also has the the elemts for 4 iteraations where as j has another element called `'e'` so the `j.hasnext` will pass the condition but you are calling `i.next` inside the inner loop with out checking any `hasnext()`. There it will throw the no such element exception because i does not contain any element after that.

```
1st iteration : j - > a and i -> 1
       j.hasnext() -> true -> j.next and i.next
2nd iteration : j -> b and i -> 2
       j.hasnext() -> true -> j.next and i.next
3rd iteration : j -> c and i -> 3
       j.hasnext() -> true -> j.next and i.next 
4th iteration : j -> d and i -> 4
       j.hasnext() -> true -> j.next and i.next throws exception
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above, has an unchecked i.next() in the inner loop. I'm not particularly sure, whether that was intentional or not, but if it was intentional, there's no need for a nested loop, and just one loop iterating both:

```
Iterator<Suit> i = suits.iterator();
for(Iterator<rank> j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext();)
    if(i.hasNext())
       deck.add(new Card(i.next(), j.next()));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(Iterator<Suit> i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
          Suit tmp = i.next();
          for(Iterator<Rank> j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext();)
            deck.add(new Card(tmp, j.next()));
}
```

this should fix it. you were calling i.next() inside the inner loop.which is not something I think you intended to do.

In your code, inside the inner loop you dont check if i.hasNext() beofre calling i.next(). That is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

You are stopping the for loop just by checking j.hasNext();. So you have to add i.hasnext() statement.